# DialogFragment in Android with theme

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm building my first app in android. I've made a dialogFragment, but it doesn't look nice enough.For having a style and a theme I used this `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,0)`. What I want is that the edge of the fragment to be black like a frame, or have its corners round. I think I must write my own style in xml and put it in styles, but I'm not sure. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 29):

As you say you'll need to create the style that you want to apply, and then assign it to your `DialogFragment` as the second parameter in the `setStyle()` method call. You must remember to make this call before you call `show()`.

So, if you create a new style named "MyStyle" in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    .
    .
    .
    <style name="MyStyle">
        .
        .
        .
    </style>
    .
    .
    .
</resources>
```

Then use this in your setStyle call:

```
DialogFragment dial = (DialogFragment) Fragment.instantiate(this, MyDialogFragment.class.getCanonicalName());
dial.setStyle( DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyStyle );
dial.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.Well that's both good and bad news.See i have no idea of how to build something like that in xml.Do you know any tutorials/sample codes ?

Comment: There are lots of examples on my blog: http://blog.stylingandroid.com.  Specifically, there are some articles on applying styles to AlertDialog which may be of the most relevance to you: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/271