# Android Google Map in FragmentDialog being overlayed by the Dialog's own gray overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

I just migrated a MapView from an Activity's layout to a DialogFragment. It was a pretty painless migration:

A button on the activity launches the dialog, setting the `LatLng`    the map requires:

```
case R.id.btn_open_map:
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager
                        = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DirectionsMapDialogFragment mapDialogFragment = new DirectionsMapDialogFragment();
                mapDialogFragment.setLatLng(mLatLng);
                mapDialogFragment.setRetainInstance(false);
                mapDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "fragmentName");
            break;
```

In the fragment itself it's all pretty standard code. I do however use a custom layout, as I have a button overlaying the map which launches the GoogleMaps app:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context="com.alexrafa.meetmi.fragments.DirectionsMapFragment"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mv_location_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="APIKEY"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_grey600_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_directions"
        android:background="@drawable/background_map_button"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_get_map_directions" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Notice how I tried setting the background to transparent in the `FrameLayout`. I did it because it seems my map is overlayed by the standard gray overlay all Dialogs have in Android:

[image: The DialogFragment showing the map]

And it's not an API auth problem, all the map's functions work perfectly. How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems your dialog fragment is using Holo Theme for map dialog fragment.Try to set a differet theme for your DirectionsMapDialogFragment.You can find link here to launch dialog frament with theme attribute : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469084/dialogfragment-in-android-with-theme

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I tried setting a style but no luck...

Comment: Did you try to set Dialog's background from code.Something like this:  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent));

Comment: Well I'm getting better results using mapDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,
                        android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);

And experimenting with the second parameter. Turns out you were right. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how I ended up fixing my little predicament:
I set a theme for the dialog, specifically `mapDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);`

And added some top and bottom padding in the layout. The result:
[image: Fixed dialog]

Big up to saurabh1489 for helping me find the answer!