# How to set the theme for DialogFragment

Tags: android

Can someone please explain why this statement works perfectly well:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
```

and the next statement does not deliver

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.dialog);
```

This is what I have in the style's department:

```xml
<style
    name="dialog">
    <!-- title encapsulating main part (backgroud) of custom alertdialog -->
    <item
        name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <!-- turn off any drawable used to draw a frame on the window -->
    <item
        name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <!-- turn off any drawable used to draw a frame on the window -->
    <item
        name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <!-- float the window so it does not fill the screen -->
    <item
        name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- remove the title bar we make our own-->
    <item
        name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <!-- remove the shadow from under the title bar -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 45):

Try using the code in onCreate of the fragment as

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.dialog);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24375599/2898715 it's also possible to omit the `setStyle` call altogether, and define the defulat style that `DialogFragments` will use throughout the whole app.

`styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- makes all dialogs in your app use your dialog theme by default -->
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">?alertDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="dialogTheme">?alertDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">?alertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <!-- define your dialog theme -->
    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.MinWidth">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_green</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/green</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    .....
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        .....
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a parent theme like

```
<style name="dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> Your theme attributes </style>
```

Comment: @blackbelt: I'm noy allowed to place pictures so it's a bit hard to explain in words.

Comment: I tried that; but no change. The direct use of Theme_Holo gives me the expected dark background without a title; just what I want.  The use of my own style "dialog" presents me with a dialog box that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing so through programming like below:-

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.dialog);
```

or can be declared in xml file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the bottomSheetDialogFragment from the activty:

```
var bottomFragment = ServiceOtpVerficationFragment()
bottomFragment.setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,R.style.BottomSheetTheme)
bottomFragment.show(supportFragmentManager,"TAG")
```

````
Add this in styles.xml
    
    <style name="BottomSheetTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">        
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

And In the fragment add extension as `BottomSheetDialogFragment()` to fragment class using colon.```
````