# Lollipop v21, FragmentDialog doesn't take my activity theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialogfragment

I have my activity theme as below set.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

The activity have a simple FragmentDialog that is started using (Kotlin code)

```
    MyDialogFragment().show(supportFragmentManager, MyDialogFragment.TAG)
```

The MyDialogFragment does have a Button. Hence I expect the color of the Button is colorPrimary as per the theme. However the color of the Button (on v21) is only grey)

This works on Marshmallow (i.e. v23) and not Lollipop (v21). I haven't tried v22. ... So I guess the v21 doesn't automatically inherit the theme from the activity.

For KitKat and below, this doesn't apply, as it doesn't use 'android:colorButtonNormal'

How should I get my FragmentDialog get the theme that I set on my activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, which is to explicitly define my FragmentDialog theme as below, on top of defining my activity theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Then I need to explicitly set it from my FragmentDialog onCreate().

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
}
```

Note: It has to be in onCreate as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26582301/3286489

I'm still open to more elegant answer if there's any out there.