# Android DialogFragment with AppCompat theme issue

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-dialogfragment

I've trying to create DialoFragment with AppCompat theme, but when i use AppCompat theme, dialog title is not shown.

I'am using defined style:

```
<style name="DialogFragment" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"/>
```

When parent theme will be changed to:

```
<style name="DialogFragment" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog"/>
```

or

```
<style name="DialogFragment" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"/>
```

title is displaying properly.

Code of my dialog:

```
public class InfoDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = InfoDialog.class.getName();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title));

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogFragment);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, container, false);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is causing the issue?
Application use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0`, maybe this is platform bug?

Comment: did you find correct solution?

Answer (score 14):

Try extending [AppCompatDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.html) instead of DialogFragment. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` sets no title window in default.

Try something like below:

```
<style name="DialogFragment" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As far as i know once you override onCreateView you are overriding the default layout of the dialogFragment. so i suggest that you create the whole custom dialog fragment layout.

here's a sample xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/rounded_dialog"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard"
        >


        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_error_prompt_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_standard"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_standard"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_standard"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_error_prompt_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_long"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard">

        <TextView
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_standard"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_error_prompt_positive_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_height"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_standard"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_button_selector_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard"
            android:text="@string/ok"`enter code here`
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
            android:textColor="@color/background_floating_material_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is faked dialog with title.. Some elements are missing.. Like line separation between title and rest of the dialog.