# DialogFragment return onClick result to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

This has been asked and answered at least a dozen times yet I still can't get mine going. I've tried 4 or more of the listed answers and get no errors, a result simply isn't returned. here's the most recent code that I've tried. I really wanted this solution to work because it was the most readable to me.

I welcome any suggestions, Thanks.

*MainActivity*

```
...
private void showAlertDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyAlertDialogFragment alertDialog = 
    MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance("Some title");
    alertDialog.setTargetFragment(alertDialog, 1);
    alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intentdata)
{
    // Stuff to do, dependent on requestCode and resultCode
    if(requestCode == 1)  // 1 is an arbitrary number, can be any int
    {
        // This is the return result of your DialogFragment
        if(resultCode == 1) // 1 is an arbitrary number, can be any int
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result received",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("onActivityResult", "result received" + resultCode);
        }
    }
}
```

*MyDialogFragment*

```
...
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

...

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new
    AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",  new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // on success
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 
            1, getActivity().getIntent());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}
```

Comment: Where is `getTargetFragment()` method?

Comment: I think it's just built-in, I haven't overridden it anywhere.

Comment: Take a look at the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32638343/4409409

Comment: I got it going now. not sure if it's proper, but it works and I posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, added a `onDialogOKPressed` method to my `MainActivity` and put this inside the onClick of my dialog `((MainActivity)(MyAlertDialogFragment.this.getActivity())).onDialogOKPressed();`

so now it looks like this

*MyDialogFragment*

```
...
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // on success
            ((MainActivity)(MyAlertDialogFragment.this.getActivity())).onDialogOKPressed();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 1, getActivity().getIntent());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}
```

*MainActivity*

```
...
public void onDialogOKPressed () {
    // Stuff to do, dependent on requestCode and resultCode
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```